# Localization file path error when using tap-i18n with meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor

I am running meteor inside a folder, like this

```
ROOT_URL="http://localhost:3000/registration" meteor
```

Also, i am using tap:i18n package for internationalisation support. The problem is that tap_i18n doesn't update the url for the localisation files and still makes request to `http://localhost:3000/tap-i18n/en-US.json` which is not a valid address, and hence throws 404 error. It should make request to `http://localhost:3000/registration/tap-i18n/en-US.json`. Notice the registration folder that was passed via ROOT_URL while starting meteor.

How can i tell tap_i18n package to honor ROOT_URL?

Comment: can you provide some code for testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ranjan,

I've setup a small demo project with some explanations on how to achieve your configuration. Please let me know if you could solve your issue.

[How to configure tap:i18n with custom ROOT_URL](https://github.com/meteorpoly/sof-i18n-demo/blob/master/README.md)

[image: Here is the solution outline]

Comment: Ranjan did you try my solution?

Comment: It worked, thanks :) I was on vacation, so i tried it now itself. Let me see if i can award the bounty to you now.

Answer (score 0):

Check the configuration, you can set the i18n_files_route parameter

> Configuring tap-i18n
>
> To configure tap-i18n add to it a file named project-tap.i18n.
>
> This JSON can have the following properties. All of them are optional.
>   The values bellow are the defaults.
>
> project-root/project-tap.i18n
>   ----------------------------- {
>       "helper_name": "_",
>       "supported_languages": null,
>       "i18n_files_route": "/tap-i18n",
>       "cdn_path": null 
>   }

[Source link for configuration](https://github.com/TAPevents/tap-i18n#configuring-tap-i18n)

Comment: i tried using i18n_files_route as /tap-i18n and /register/tap-i18n. with /tap-i18n i get a 404 error, and with /register/tap-18n i don't get 404 error for the language file, but it doesn't load the json file, instead it gets the base page HTML. :(